# How to read serial data from a bluetooth port? C++

Tags: c++, windows, bluetooth, serial-port, usb

I created a program to read serial data from a COM port using C++, however due to changes in my project I have to read data from a BT port. Since Im using a bluetooth adapter to connect my computer to the device I expected the reading process to be the same but apparently it is not. Since Im using the Window OS to perform this task GetLastError() returns 2 which means the specified file is not found. However when I use Arduino's serial monitor the data is read just fine. Does anyone know how to read from a BT port in C++? Im using Windows 8 by the way, here is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
///-----------------------------Open port-----------------------------------------------------------------

// Name of port where device is found
LPCWSTR port = L"COM40";

// Open port for reading
HANDLE hComm = ::CreateFile(port, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);

// Check if port has been opened succesfully
if (hComm == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) std::cout << "Failed to open " << port << " error: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
else std::cout << port << " has been opened succesfully\n";

///-----------------------------Configure port------------------------------------------------------------

// Create DCB structure 
DCB dcb = { 0 };

// Get Comm state
if (!::GetCommState(hComm, &dcb)) std::cout << "Failed to get Comm state, error: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;

// Configure strcutre
dcb.DCBlength = sizeof(DCB);

// Set Baud rate
dcb.BaudRate = CBR_9600;
// Set number of bytes in bits that are recieved through the port
dcb.ByteSize = 8;
dcb.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;

// Check if port has been configured correctly
if (!::SetCommState(hComm, &dcb)) std::cout << "\nFailed to set Comm State, error: " << GetLastError();
else std::cout << "Comm state has been set succesfully\n";

///-----------------------------Read data-------------------------------------------------------------------

char buffer;
DWORD maxBytes = 1;
if (!::ReadFile(hComm, &buffer, maxBytes, NULL, NULL)) std::cout << "\nFailed to read from " << port << " error: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
else std::cout << "File has been read succesfully\n";

///-----------------------------Write to text file----------------------------------------------------------

std::fstream file;
int counter = 0;
// Writing to text file will be done later
while (ReadFile(hComm, &buffer, maxBytes, NULL, NULL))
{
    std::cout << buffer;
}

///-----------------------------Close port------------------------------------------------------------------

CloseHandle(hComm);
file.close();

std::cout << "\nCOM40 has been closed!\n";
return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Depending in the type of bluetooth device you use it should make no difference: I worked with "real", USB and Bluetooth serial ports and all werde treated the same because Windows created a virtual com port vor them

Comment: Did you solved your problem? If not I can share answer the question.